# How get messageSource's message if the locale doesn't have a property file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I have defined only french and US english files (`messages_en_US.properties`, `messages_fr.properties`). I have also created a bean locale resolver to set the default as en-US:

```
@Configuration
public class LocalizationConfig
{    
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver()
    {
        SessionLocaleResolver resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();

        //Default to the US
        resolver.setDefaultLocale( Locale.US );

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

But when I call the below method, it throws a "NoSuchMessageException":

```
messageSource.getMessage(
    "test.message",
    new Object[] {},
    Locale.GERMAN
```

);

How do I make it use the default if the locale asked for doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename messages_en_US.properties to messages.properties. It will become the default message bundle for any locale except "fr" in your case.

Comment: The issue was I needed to add a bean for `MessageSource` and set the basename to the proper directory in there.